# How to unblur current iframe with current created button

Tags: javascript, html, function, iframe

On my page I have an add button and a text input. If you put an embeded link into the text input then it shows the youtube video on the page and automatically blurs it, puts a SHOW button on it, and under the video there will be also created a HIDE button to blur it back if you want to. The problem that I have is that if I create multiple videos then the SHOW button unblurs the video thats on the top of the page and not the one which I clicked. Anyone knows how to fix it?

This is how my js looks like:

```
function newElement() {
  var inputValue = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
  if (inputValue.includes("https://" && "embed")) {
    var everyElement = document.createElement("div");
    document.body.appendChild(everyElement);

    var element = document.createElement("div"); // Creates a div for the iframe and the hide button
    element.className = "page";
    everyElement.appendChild(element);

    var element2 = document.createElement("iframe"); // Creates the iframe video
    element2.allowFullscreen = "allowfullscreen";
    element2.src = inputValue;
    element2.height = "880";
    element2.width = "100%";
    element2.style.filter = "blur(20px)";
    element2.frameBorder = "0";
    element2.id = "image";
    document.getElementById("myInput").value = "";
    element.appendChild(element2);

    var element3 = document.createElement("button"); // Creates the SHOW button on the video to lock it
    element3.id = "btnID";
    element3.className = "bg-text";
    element3.onclick = function show() {
      document.getElementById("image").style.filter = "blur(0)";
      document.getElementById("image").style.pointerEvents = "auto";

      document.getElementById("btnID").style.display = "none";
    };
  }
  element3.textContent = "Show";
  element.appendChild(element3);

  var element4 = document.createElement("button"); // Creates the HIDE button under the video to blur it back
  element4.id = "btnHID";
  element4.className = "hideBtn";
  element4.textContent = "Hide";
  element4.onclick = function hide() {
    document.getElementById("image").style.filter = "blur(20px)";
    document.getElementById("image").style.pointerEvents = "none";

    document.getElementById("btnID").style.display = "initial";
  };
  everyElement.appendChild(element4);
}

// https://www.youtube.com/embed/G6xgMW7U0aY
// <iframe width="947" height="721" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/G6xgMW7U0aY" title="Future - 712PM (Directed by Travis Scott)" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Secret</title>
</head>
<body>  
    <div class="addPlc">
        <input type="text" id="myInput" placeholder="Link...">
        <span onclick="newElement()" class="addBtn">Add</span>
    </div>
    <div id="myUL">
        
    </div>                 
        
    <script src="code.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is how it looks when u create it and also this is how it should look after u press the HIDE button
[image: This is how it looks when u create it and also this is how it should look after u press the HIDE button]

This is how it looks if you press the SHOW button
[image: This is how it looks if you press the SHOW button]

Comment: hi Daniel. welcome to stack overflow. please add your `html` and some information or picture. @Daniel

Comment: I added my my html and some pictures